# Netbeans PHP Project

Tags: php, netbeans, configuration

I have installed netbeans 7.4 with PHP plugins.

Netbeans does not show the PHP category when I am trying to create a new project, even though the PHP plugin is visible in the `Installed` tab in `Tools > Plugins`.

Comment: Did you download the correct netbeans bundle at https://netbeans.org/downloads/? Because not all bundles have php included.

Comment: Yes this is correct netbeans bundle(All).

Answer (score 0):

go to Tools then Plugins.
Then in Installed tab see if php is Active or not. Activate it if its not.

Even if its not activated in New Project it should show PHP(dunno about 7.4) as it gives in 7.2

Answer (score 0):

I got solution,its work for me. Reinstall PHP plugin again. Steps are as below:

1. Go to Tools then Plugins
2. Move to Installed tab
3. Select PHP and Uninstall it.
4. After uninstall go to Available Plugins and install PHP again.

Answer (score 0):

If your plan is to use NetBrans for only PHP projects, just use the stand-alone PHP IDE: https://netbeans.org/downloads/